# Pulling a float value out Mat (java)

Tags: java, opencv, pixel

I got a home task from a company I wish to work in. It's my first time doing any kind of image processing, and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to handle Matrices.

I was instructed to handle a grayscale image, with float pixel values in the range [0,1]. I chose OpenCV (as they recommended), and chose a Mat of type CV_32F.

One of my functions gets the Mat and examines the pixels. I want to check if a pixel value is -1 (marks a pixel that should be fixed) but I can only get double[] using the Mat.get() method.
I know there's a float in there, so I tried casting but it wouldn't allow it.

Is there any other way I can check if the pixel value is -1?
Thanks in advance.

[Inability to cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvAg3.png)

Comment: Please don't post links to images or images of code.  Just post the code.  And it would help if you also posted the exact error message you saw.  You should be able to down cast the `double` to a `float`.  Did you first try copying the value to a `double` and then down casting that?

Comment: On your image, the code appears to be missing a `(`, this could be the issue.

Comment: @Bonatti Are you sure?  I can't find it.

Comment: Check again, watch the red line, see where it starts and ends, or just plain count the `(` and `)` on the `img.get` line

Comment: @Bonatti It still looks okay to me.  `if ((float)(img.get(i,j)) == -1)`

Comment: Edit your question, copy and paste (with the proper formatting), and count how many parenthesis are on the line. The image you posted, has a red line, explaining the problem. What you wrote is: 1: `img.get(i,j)`, 2 `Do nothing`, 3 `Cast to float`, 4 `Check boolean value of the float`, 5 `check if void is == -1, out of any context`.

Comment: @WJS - thanks for the quick response. Figured an image would be easier to read. As you can see I'm trying to cast an array of doubles (double[]) to a float. The exact error was "inconvertible types" as I've mentioned - I can't cast a double[] to a float. Thing is - I know there's a float in every coordinate (I generated the Mat this way) but the method Mat.get() only returns an array of doubles.
I ended up putting a patch on it - instead of generating a Mat of floats, I generated a Mat of float[] of size 1 (just holds 1 float).

Comment: @BarackCohen what exactly does `img.get(i,j)` return?  a `double` or a `double[]`?

Comment: @WJS a double[]. How do you make these grey code words btw?

Comment: That is your problem.  You can't cast an array of `doubles` to an array of `floats`.  To make the highlighted words, surround with backticks.

Comment: @WJS I knew that was my problem. Anyway I found a solution, so thanks again.